# How to make rectangular mesh from Points cloud

Tags: mesh, point-clouds

Does somebody know, how to simply and theoretically generate a rectangular mesh from a Points Cloud defined by 3D coordinates (x,y,z)?

Regards
Amine

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Do you mean rectangles or quads?

Comment: I need to make a Quads mesh

Comment: It's not always possible then. You could try to create a Delaunay triangulation from the points, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html, and then merge pairs of triangles to get a quad.

Comment: Do you have an example of Points cloud? do you want to save it to a file? which mesh format?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any methods to go directly from a point cloud to a quad mesh, but you could start by creating a triangular mesh using any standard technique:
[Algorithm for generating a triangular mesh from a cloud of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879160/algorithm-for-generating-a-triangular-mesh-from-a-cloud-of-points?rq=1).

Then, you could transform your triangular mesh to a quad one. [Here is a paper](https://imr.sandia.gov/papers/imr19/Ebeida1A.2.pdf) which describes an algorithm called "Q-TRAN." I haven't personally implemented this algorithm, but the results shown in the paper look pretty promising.